# Yii2 two models, two views, two tables

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I'm just learning a little bit how to use the framework Yii2. Now I have a specific question.

I have 2 models, 2 views and 2 tables. View 1 always appears and view 2 only when a condition in form 1 was met.

```
$model_user = new User();
$model_details = new Details();
```

Is there any way to save both models together after view 2 is filled? Currently I have the problem that the data in $model_user (view 1) is reset as soon as I submit view 2 ($model_details).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make user both view use same form  since you want to save both 2 models at same time. Adding related controller action and view code will give more insight on your problem.

Comment: From your description it's kind of hard to tell what is the workflow when filling those forms. Is form from view 1 submitted to server and than is view 2 displayed or are both views displayed on same page and the second form is only hidden with JS until first one is filled? If it's the first case you have to somehow persist the data user submitted with first form (store in db, session or in hidden fields of form 2). If its the other case you have to follow @InsaneSkull's advice to make sure data from both forms are sent to server.

Answer (score 0):

An example for a controller action could be:

```
public function actionView2() 
{
    $model_user = new User();
    $model_details = new Details();
    if ($model_user->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
      && $model_details->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        if ($model_user->save()
          && model_details->save()) 
        {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('view2', [
        'model_user' => $model_user,
        'model_details' => $model_details,
    ]);
}
```

In this action you fill both models and save it to the database.
The best: The models are only saved to the database if the rules match. So, if the user enters something incorrect, the models are not saved to the database. See [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-forms)